# navbar-toggle works great when run from computer, but not when hotsted on github

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm working my way through a coursera course.. If I run the same exact page hosted on my computer everything is great... If on githubs "pages" the navbar-toggle acts as though it has no target.

```
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <!-- Collapsed banner on mobile -->
      <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
        <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-lg">
          <li class="text-center">Chicken</li>
          <hr class="visible-xs">
          <li class="text-center">Beef</li>
          <hr class="visible-xs">
          <li class="text-center">Sushi</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Full code is up on github
https://github.com/AdamAtGalaxe/Coursera_Module_3_Solution
and the site is
https://adamatgalaxe.github.io/Coursera_Module_3_Solution/

Pretty sure its how my bootstrap is linked here vs on github...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

and

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script> code here
```

Comment: Not sure if it is anything to do with this but one thing I've noticed is that you seem to be hiding the drop down list on all screen sizes. `hidden-sm` etc. The thing making me question myself here is that you mention no problem when looking at the page locally.

Comment: Yeah, it works like butta when ran from my computer as index.html.  But....  It's definitely something with how my bootstrap is linked.  I'll update with that.